# Mikrotik. Пинг DNS 1.1.1.1 есть, а 8.8.8.8 нет. Прерывистый интернет на компьютере

Tags: linux, роутер, router, mikrotik

Компьютер подключен по кабелю к Mikrotik ether2.
Роутер подключен по кабелю к Mikrotik ether1.

Общая схема: Провайдер -> Роутер -> Mikrotik -> PC.

Работать невозможно за компьютером, поскольку интернет прерывистый и работает как-то наполовину.

Пинг с компьютера:

```
DNS 1.1.1.1 - есть;
DNS 8.8.8.8 - нет;
vk.com - сейчас есть, но потом может нет;
mail.ru - есть;
virtualbox.ru - пинга нет, потом по другому ip этого адреса пинг пошёл.;
и так далее.
```

Также при SSH подключении к компьютеру, после ввода пароля сессия может зависнуть.

Если подключить другой компьютер к Mikrotik ether2 - проблема актуальна.
Если пинговать все эти же ресурсы через Terminal Mikrotik - пинг есть всегда.
Не исключаю ошибки в настройках Mikrotik, но сбрасывать и настраивать с нуля не хотелось бы.

```
Firewall NAT: add chain=srcnat out-interface=ether1 action=masquerade
Firewall FilterRules: 
0  D ;;; special dummy rule to show fasttrack counters
      chain=forward action=passthrough 
 1    ;;; defconf: accept ICMP
      chain=input action=accept protocol=icmp dst-address=192.168.3.0/24 
      log=no log-prefix="" 
 2    chain=forward action=accept protocol=icmp dst-address=192.168.3.0/24 
      log=no log-prefix="" 
 3    chain=input action=accept protocol=udp port=1701,500,4500 
 4    chain=input action=accept protocol=ipsec-esp 
 5    chain=input action=accept protocol=ipsec-ah log=no log-prefix="" 
 6    ;;; defconf: accept established,related,untracked
      chain=input action=accept connection-state=established,related,untracked
```

Comment: С компьютера сам микротик нормально пингуется? И ещё сделайте трассировку маршрута от компа к любому из сайтов. Нет ли там лишних звеньев.

Comment: С компьютера, MikroTik не пингуется.
С компьютера, роутер пингуется.

Comment: ping 77.88.8.8 не идёт. traceroute to 77.88.8.8 (77.88.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  gateway (192.168.3.1)  0.289 ms  8.367 ms  8.355 ms
 2  192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1)  1.089 ms  1.095 ms  1.105 ms
 3  ip провайдера (ip провайдера)  2.314 ms  2.341 ms  2.364 ms
 4  внешний ip (внешний ip)  2.389 ms  2.397 ms  2.420 ms
 5  178.18.225.147.ix.dataix.ru (178.18.225.147)  9.659 ms  9.763 ms  9.796 ms
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *

Comment: маршрутизатор с торговой маркой «mikrotik» выглядит в данной схеме лишним сбойным (с ваших же слов) звеном.

Comment: Я знаю, что дело в нём. Не могу разобраться из-за каких настроек может быть такая проблема и куда смотреть, чтобы это исправить. В Гугле вопросы почти все только нет пинга, либо нет пинга по домену.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, проанализировав настройки, логи и помониторив сеть, выяснилось, что Mikrotik периодически хаотично перенаправлял пакеты в другую подсеть(раньше было настроено объединение сетей), которой уже не существует и все те настройки были удалены, но Mikrotik всё равно как-то перенаправлял, хотя настроек таких не было.

Сбросил конфигурацию на заводские настройки, настроил, всё работает.

Answer (score 2):

1. Исключи сам микротик подключив компьютер напрямую.
2. Исключи компьютер подключив другой компьютер напямую.
3. Проверь роутер на взлом,проверь нет ли прокси или пробросов в нат.
4. Сделай экспорт и посмотри понимаешь ли каждую строчку этого экспорта.
5. Покажи то что не понимаешь на форуме, чате, группе по микротикам или на стековерфлоу.

Если виноват компьютер:

1. проверь на вирусы
2. winsock catalog reset
3. переустанови драйвер на сетевую карту
4. попробуй другой кабель
5. попробуй другую сетевую карту

Comment: 1. сделано, все другие компьютеры подключенные через роутер работают стабильно. 2. сделано. 3. на первый взгляд ничего лишнего и непонятного нету. 4.,5. посмотрю, спасибо